# Prove that $x_{n} \rightarrow x$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose that we are given a point $x$ and a sequence ${(x_{n})}$ in a metric space $M$ and suppose that $f(x_{n}) \rightarrow f(x)$ for every continuous real valued function $f$ on $M$. Prove that $x_{n} \rightarrow x$

I am not able to understand how I am suppose to start with the problem.

Kindly guide me through !

Thanks!

Comment: Well, if you fix $x$, you can use the metric itself to define a real valued function $f$ such that if $f(x_n) \to f(x)$ then $x_n \to x$.

Comment: A good start  (as it often is) is to write out the full definition of what you need to prove

Comment: To echo @CalvinKhor's comment, how do you express $x_n \to x$ in terms of the metric?

Comment: $f(y) =d(x, y) $

Comment: Contrapositive. Suppose that $x_n \not\to x$. Can you find a continuous function $f$ with $f(x_n) \not\to f(x)$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. Suppose $x_n \not\to x$  then $\exists f$ such that $f(x_n) \not\to f(x$ But how can I claim that $f$ is continuous or find a continuous function with the property mentioned.

Comment: @shakunimama it is just about the simplest function you can think of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the metric $d$. Verify that $d(\_,x):M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function. Apply your assumption to $d(\_,x)$. Conclude that $d(x_{n},x)\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: How will I show that $d$ is a continuous function ?

Comment: Let $z\in M$ be arbitrary. The function $d(\_,x):M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at $z$ iff for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta >0$ such that whenever $y\in M$ and $d(y,z)<\delta$, we have $|d(y,x)-d(z,x)|<\epsilon$. Hint: use the triangle inequality.

Comment: Let us define $f$ such that $f(y) = d(y,x)$. To prove that $f$ is continuous. Let $(y_{n}) \in M$ be a sequence such that $y_{n} \rightarrow y$ then for $\epsilon > 0 $ $\exists$ $n_{0}$ $\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d(y_{n}, y) < \epsilon$  $\forall  n  \ge n_{0}$ 

Now, $f(y_{n})= d(y_{n}, x)$
applying the triangle inequality we have $f(y_{n}) \le d(x,y) + \epsilon$ i.e. $f(y_{n}) - f(y) \le \epsilon$ $\forall$ $n \ge n_{0}$. 

Therefore, $f(y_{n}) \rightarrow f(y)$. We can conclude $f$ is continuous.